# Error using twitter R package's userTimlien

Tags: data-mining, r

I am using twitteR package to retrievie timeline data. My request looks as follows:

`tweets <- try(userTimeline(user , n=50),silent=TRUE)`

and this worked quite well for a time, but now I receive this error message:

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : easy handle already used in multi handle
```

In a related question on Stackoverflow one answer is to use Rcurl directly but this does not seem to work with twitteR package. Anybody got an idea on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be working well on my configuration:

Ubuntu Vivid and R:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] twitteR_1.1.8

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] bit_1.1-12     bit64_0.9-4    bitops_1.0-6   DBI_0.3.1      httr_0.6.1    
 [6] magrittr_1.5   RCurl_1.95-4.6 rjson_0.2.15   stringi_0.4-1  stringr_1.0.0 
[11] tools_3.1.2
```

Maybe you should update packages versions?